Can the Asset Library be used like Hero Forge? If not, how can it be done?
I need to create lots of characters using hundreds of props and clothing and poses. All those props/cloths are already assets that can be dragged and dropped using the Asset Library. However, they are dropped wherever I place the cursor.
My question is, can the assets go to a specific place set in advance and be automatically parented to a rig/bone? I've seen this functionality used for custom miniatures 3d-printing services like Hero Forge.
If not possible with the Asset Library, how could it be done in Blender?
Thanks! :)

Something I've done in the past is to simply have all of your assets in the same file parented to your rig, and then you can just toggle them on and off in there. Its definitely not as convenient as what you're describing but I think it would at least be a solution

Yeah, that's what I've been doing so far, but it chews up a lot of storage since I need to have all the characters available at any time for changes/modifications. I hope there's a more efficient way...
